# value of an attribute doesn't change

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to change the value of the 'd' attribute on the path element but it doesn't change, no error is thrown - [Demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/E_wZ_d-2/3/edit).

HTML:

```
<path class="slds-progress-ring__path" data-id="slds-progress-ring-path-1" d="M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 1 -2.4492935982947064e-16 L 0 0"></path>
```

JS:

```
this.template.querySelector('path[data-id=slds-progress-ring-path-1]').d = 'M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 -0.8090169943749475 -0.587785252292473 L 0 0';
```

[Demo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/E_wZ_d-2/3/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to set the elements property.
Directly assigning a value is not supported.

```
this.template.querySelector('path[data-id=slds-progress-ring-path-1]').setAttribute("d", "M 1 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 -0.8090169943749475 -0.587785252292473 L 0 0");
```

Comment: thanks again Anmol Kumar